# Is it possible to extend byte array?

Tags: java

I am implementing AES for an assignment, and would like to encapsulate the logic of checking that a key is always an array of bytes whose length is exactly 16, 24 or 32.

I can create a wrapper class that stores the bytes as a byte[] internally, but I wonder if it is possible to extend Array or something similar so that I don't have to reimplement Iterators, toString and other convenience methods that I get from using Java array.

I.e. is something like the following possible?

```
public class Key extends Array<Byte>{

    // Valid length of key in bytes
    public static int[] possibleLengths = new int[]{ 16, 24, 32 };

    // Check if a given byte[] is a valid candidate for a key
    public static boolean isValidLength(byte[] input) {
        for (int length: possibleLengths) {
            if (input.length == length) return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    // Primary constructor passes bytes directly to internal state
    public Key(byte[] input) throws InvalidKeyLengthException {
        if (!isValidLength(input))
            throw new InvalidKeyLengthException;

        setKey(input);
    }
}
```

Comment: It seems it would make more sense for the byte array to be a field on a `Key` class.

Comment: @chrylis that's how I initially went to implement, just wanted to check if I was reinventing the wheel. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it is not possible to extend the array classes.

I believe it is possible to extend ArrayList, however, which might get you close enough to what you want. You would need to disable ArrayList's ability to arbitrarily expands its capacity, however.

That said, you should probably follow to the guideline "Prefer aggregation over inheritance" in this case and just make your  array or ArrayList a field within your class.

Answer (score 3):

Well...no.  You can't extend an array type, because [it's dynamically generated](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-10.html) upon array instantiation.

It would make far more sense to have this as a field to a wrapper class (namely `Key`).

If you're concerned about having to use helper methods and the like, then you could simply delegate the major responsibilities (namely exposing the array and exposing a sensible `toString()`).

Answer (score 1):

Array is a weird notion. They do have some properties, like length although they are not a class, so you can't extend them like you are attempting.

You may convert it to `ArrayList`:

```
new ArrayList<Byte>(Arrays.asList(Key))
```

so, you may create a class extending `ArrayList` and add your new functionalists to it.
Then convert the `Byte` `Array` as said above to your custom class and check your requirements with your newly extended methods freely!